# How can I select quoted strings that are outside html tags?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am working on a syntax highlighter in ruby. From this input string (processed per line):

```
"left"<div class="wer">"test"</div>"right"
var car = ['Toyota', 'Honda']
```

How can I find `"left"`, and `"right"` in the first line, `'Toyota'`, and `'Honda'` on the second line?

I have `(["'])(\\\1|[^\1]*?)\1` to highlight the quoted strings. I am struggling with the negative look behind part of the regex.

I tried appending another regex `(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)`, but I can't get it to work with quoted strings. It works with simple alphanumeric only.

Comment: Can you clarify what your input string is?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: If you can use an HTML parser, if you can't know that regex can fail to work well in certain cases. Try [`<[^<>]*>|("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')`](http://rubular.com/r/MvmWNRnmtI) and get the first capture group. If you need to get the contents inside quotes, try [`<[^<>]*>|(?:"(?<q>[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|'(?<q>[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)')`](http://rubular.com/r/AIGeYlcIXJ) and only get the `q` named capture group.

Comment: I suggest to read the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your expression, I am able to use the tokenization + ruby loop to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can match one or more tokens by creating groups using parentheses in regex, and using `|` to create an or condition:

```
/("left")|("right")|('Toyota')|('Honda')/
```

Here's an example:

http://rubular.com/r/C8ONnxKYEV

**EDIT**

Just saw the tile of your question specified that you want to search outside HTML tags.

Unfortunately this isn't possible using only Regular expressions. The reason is that HTML, along with any language that requires delimiters like `""`, `''`, `()`, aren't regular. In other words, regexes don't contain a way of distinguishing levels of nesting and therefore you'll need to use a parser along with your Regex. If you're doing this strictly in Ruby, consider using a tool like Nokogiri or Mechanize to properly parse and interact with the DOM.

Comment: I see, this is what have been suggested also in another question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This Ruby script first finds and replaces the HTML tags, note this is not perfect, and is susceptible to many edge cases. Then the script just looks for all the single and double quoted values.

```
str = %Q["left" <div class="wer">"test"</div>"right"\n]
str = str + %Q<var car = ['Toyota', 'Honda']>    
puts "SourceString: \n" + str + "\n\n"

str.gsub!(/(?:<([a-z]+)(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?>).*?<\/\1>/i, '_')
puts "SourceString after replacement: \n" + str + "\n\n"

puts "array of quoted values"
str.scan(/"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/)
```

**Sample Output**

```
SourceString: 
"left" <div class="wer">"test"</div>"right"
var car = ['Toyota', 'Honda']

SourceString after replacement: 
"left" _"right"
var car = ['Toyota', 'Honda']

=> ["\"left\"", "\"right\"", "'Toyota'", "'Honda'"]
```

**Live Example**

https://repl.it/CRGo

## HTML Parsing

I do recommend using an HTML parsing engine instead. This one seems pretty decent for Ruby: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/html_parsing

Comment: I would wrap the found strings in a span, but how would I swap back the previous html tags in the correct place with your solution?  Btw I have solved it already @WiktorStribiżew's expression in his comment.

Comment: That's beyond the scope of your original question where you were simply asking for how to find the quoted strings. With this new information I recommend using an HTML parsing engine to find and replace. This could  be accomplished with https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/html_parsing, or via jquery after page load.

Comment: It is within details of the question, selecting the quoted string is just a part of the overall solution, but thanks anyway.